# Sql 2008 Logins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was wanderin what is the difference when login with:

Server name:User
Authentication: windows authentication

and

Server name:User\sqlexpress
Authentication: windows authentication

I'm asking because i wasn't able to give sysadmin role to the 'user\sqlexpress' but i could on 'User'
Sorry for the question if it is too simple but i couldn't find an thorogh eplanation on the web.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the \sqlexpress refers to the database instance. If you have multiple instances running on the same server you could give each a different name. You would then connect to each instance separately and give permission to the user in each instance.

From SQL database perspective the "\sqexpress" part is meaningless as it has already been specified when you connect to the database with your admin tool to give the permissions.